# What are the limits of SLA 3D printing for optical lenses (e.g. glasses)

Tags: print-quality, resin, sla

I'm interested in making optical lenses, but I do not want to spend too much on it. What are the limits and criteria which will help me decide which SLA printer will make it possible or not?

I suppose the first criterion will be the resolution which will require more or less polishing afterwards, but are there other things to check and some which would constitute an absolute no-go with low-range machines?

Comment: Seems to me the most important criteria is how transparent is the resin after it's cured. If it's not transparent enough, it doesn't matter how much (or little) you have to polish it, you won't get light through it.

Comment: You are right about that, but the fact that this technology IS used, means that resins which are OK for that DO exist. e.g.: https://formlabs.com/blog/creating-camera-lenses-with-stereolithography/